# After update Word 2013 (KB3115173) adding header and footer in document by OOXML broken

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, office-js, word-addins

After i installed the latest update for Word 2013 (KB3115173), the code to add headers and footers with an Add-In doesn't work anymore.

The code is executed correctly but the header and footer are missing in the document i just created.

```
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(OOXMLHeaderAndFooter, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Ooxml}
```

the OOXMLHeaderAndFooter is looking like:

```
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/footer1.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footer+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:ftr mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
        <w:p w:rsidR="005E294E" w:rsidRDefault="00B4473B" w:rsidP="00D157A3">
          <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Footer"/>
          </w:pPr>
          <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
              <w:noProof/>
            </w:rPr>
            <mc:AlternateContent>
              <mc:Choice Requires="wps">
                <w:drawing>
                  <wp:anchor distT="45720" distB="45720" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251661312" behindDoc="0" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" wp14:anchorId="0433755B" wp14:editId="4529E087">
                    <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
                    <wp:positionH relativeFrom="page">
                      <wp:posOffset>7375525</wp:posOffset>
                    </wp:positionH>
                    <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
                      <wp:posOffset>300726</wp:posOffset>
                    </wp:positionV>
                    <wp:extent cx="342900" cy="335915"/>
                    <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
                    <wp:wrapSquare wrapText="bothSides"/>
                    <wp:docPr id="217" name="Text Box 2"/>
                    <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                      <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>
                    </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                      <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                        <wps:wsp>
                          <wps:cNvSpPr txBox="1">
                            <a:spLocks noChangeArrowheads="1"/>
                          </wps:cNvSpPr>
                          <wps:spPr bwMode="auto">
                            <a:xfrm>
                              <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                              <a:ext cx="342900" cy="335915"/>
                            </a:xfrm>
                            <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                              <a:avLst/>
                            </a:prstGeom>
                            <a:noFill/>
                            <a:ln w="9525">
                              <a:noFill/>
                              <a:miter lim="800000"/>
                              <a:headEnd/>
                              <a:tailEnd/>
                            </a:ln>
                          </wps:spPr>
                          <wps:txbx>
                            <w:txbxContent>
                              <w:p w:rsidR="00D90467" w:rsidRPr="006C60DD" w:rsidRDefault="00B4473B" w:rsidP="00D157A3">
                                <w:pPr>
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                                  </w:rPr>
                                </w:pPr>
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="006C60DD">
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
                                </w:r>
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="006C60DD">
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> PAGE   * MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
                                </w:r>
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="006C60DD">
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
                                </w:r>
                                <w:r w:rsidR="00491EB0">
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:noProof/>
                                    <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:t>1</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="006C60DD">
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:noProof/>
                                    <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
                                </w:r>
                              </w:p>
                              <w:p w:rsidR="00D90467" w:rsidRDefault="00B4473B" w:rsidP="00D157A3"/>
                            </w:txbxContent>
                          </wps:txbx>
                          <wps:bodyPr rot="0" vert="horz" wrap="square" lIns="91440" tIns="45720" rIns="91440" bIns="45720" anchor="t" anchorCtr="0">
                            <a:noAutofit/>
                          </wps:bodyPr>
                        </wps:wsp>
                      </a:graphicData>
                    </a:graphic>
                    <wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="margin">
                      <wp14:pctWidth>0</wp14:pctWidth>
                    </wp14:sizeRelH>
                    <wp14:sizeRelV relativeFrom="margin">
                      <wp14:pctHeight>0</wp14:pctHeight>
                    </wp14:sizeRelV>
                  </wp:anchor>
                </w:drawing>
              </mc:Choice>
              <mc:Fallback>
                <w:pict>
                  <v:shapetype w14:anchorId="0433755B" id="_x0000_t202" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="202" path="m,l,21600r21600,l21600,xe">
                    <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
                    <v:path gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
                  </v:shapetype>
                  <v:shape id="Text Box 2" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" type="#_x0000_t202" style="position:absolute;margin-left:580.75pt;margin-top:23.7pt;width:27pt;height:26.45pt;z-index:251661312;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:3.6pt;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:3.6pt;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:page;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-width-relative:margin;mso-height-relative:margin;v-text-anchor:top" o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#xA;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#xA;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#xA;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#xA;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#xA;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#xA;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#xA;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#xA;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#xA;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#xA;IQDgknKLCgIAAPMDAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysU9tuGyEQfa/Uf0C813ux3cQr4yhNmqpS&#xA;epGSfgBmWS8qMBSwd9Ovz8A6jtW+VeUBATNzZs6ZYX01Gk0O0gcFltFqVlIirYBW2R2jPx7v3l1S&#xA;EiK3LddgJaNPMtCrzds368E1soYedCs9QRAbmsEx2sfomqIIopeGhxk4adHYgTc84tXvitbzAdGN&#xA;LuqyfF8M4FvnQcgQ8PV2MtJNxu86KeK3rgsyEs0o1hbz7vO+TXuxWfNm57nrlTiWwf+hCsOVxaQn&#xA;qFseOdl79ReUUcJDgC7OBJgCuk4JmTkgm6r8g81Dz53MXFCc4E4yhf8HK74evnuiWkbr6oISyw02&#xA;6VGOkXyAkdRJn8GFBt0eHDrGEZ+xz5lrcPcgfgZi4abndievvYehl7zF+qoUWZyFTjghgWyHL9Bi&#xA;Gr6PkIHGzpskHspBEB379HTqTSpF4ON8Ua9KtAg0zefLVbXMGXjzEux8iJ8kGJIOjHpsfQbnh/sQ&#xA;UzG8eXFJuSzcKa1z+7UlA6OrZb3MAWcWoyJOp1aG0csyrWleEsePts3BkSs9nTGBtkfSiefEOI7b&#xA;ER2TElton5C+h2kK8dfgoQf/m5IBJ5DR8GvPvaREf7Yo4apaLNLI5stieVHjxZ9btucWbgVCMRop&#xA;mY43MY/5xPUape5UluG1kmOtOFlZneMvSKN7fs9er3918wwAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAO3j&#xA;xO3fAAAADAEAAA8AAABkcnMvZG93bnJldi54bWxMj81OwzAQhO9IvIO1SNyonZIUmsapKhBXUMuP&#xA;xM2Nt0nUeB3FbhPenu0Jbju7o9lvivXkOnHGIbSeNCQzBQKp8ralWsPH+8vdI4gQDVnTeUINPxhg&#xA;XV5fFSa3fqQtnnexFhxCITcamhj7XMpQNehMmPkeiW8HPzgTWQ61tIMZOdx1cq7UQjrTEn9oTI9P&#xA;DVbH3clp+Hw9fH+l6q1+dlk/+klJckup9e3NtFmBiDjFPzNc8BkdSmba+xPZIDrWySLJ2KshfUhB&#xA;XBzzJOPNniel7kGWhfxfovwFAAD//wMAUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhALaDOJL+AAAA4QEAABMAAAAA&#xA;AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFtDb250ZW50X1R5cGVzXS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAOP0h/9YAAACU&#xA;AQAACwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAvAQAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHNQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEA4JJyiwoCAADz&#xA;AwAADgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAuAgAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEA7ePE7d8A&#xA;AAAMAQAADwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABkBAAAZHJzL2Rvd25yZXYueG1sUEsFBgAAAAAEAAQA8wAAAHAF&#xA;AAAAAA==&#xA;" filled="f" stroked="f">
                    <v:textbox>
                      <w:txbxContent>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="00D90467" w:rsidRPr="006C60DD" w:rsidRDefault="00B4473B" w:rsidP="00D157A3">
                          <w:pPr>
                            <w:rPr>
                              <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                          </w:pPr>
                          <w:r w:rsidRPr="006C60DD">
                            <w:rPr>
                              <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
                          </w:r>
                          <w:r w:rsidRPr="006C60DD">
                            <w:rPr>
                              <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> PAGE   * MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
                          </w:r>
                          <w:r w:rsidRPr="006C60DD">
                            <w:rPr>
                              <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
                          </w:r>
                          <w:r w:rsidR="00491EB0">
                            <w:rPr>
                              <w:noProof/>
                              <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:t>1</w:t>
                          </w:r>
                          <w:r w:rsidRPr="006C60DD">
                            <w:rPr>
                              <w:noProof/>
                              <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
                          </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="00D90467" w:rsidRDefault="00B4473B" w:rsidP="00D157A3"/>
                      </w:txbxContent>
                    </v:textbox>
                    <w10:wrap type="square" anchorx="page"/>
                  </v:shape>
                </w:pict>
              </mc:Fallback>
            </mc:AlternateContent>
          </w:r>
          <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
              <w:noProof/>
            </w:rPr>
            <mc:AlternateContent>
              <mc:Choice Requires="wps">
                <w:drawing>
                  <wp:anchor distT="45720" distB="45720" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251662336" behindDoc="1" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" wp14:anchorId="729764EB" wp14:editId="35078F52">
                    <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
                    <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column">
                      <wp:posOffset>2981325</wp:posOffset>
                    </wp:positionH>
                    <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
                      <wp:posOffset>290566</wp:posOffset>
                    </wp:positionV>
                    <wp:extent cx="2360930" cy="1404620"/>
                    <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
                    <wp:wrapTight wrapText="bothSides">
                      <wp:wrapPolygon edited="0">
                        <wp:start x="517" y="0"/>
                        <wp:lineTo x="517" y="20176"/>
                        <wp:lineTo x="21014" y="20176"/>
                        <wp:lineTo x="21014" y="0"/>
                        <wp:lineTo x="517" y="0"/>
                      </wp:wrapPolygon>
                    </wp:wrapTight>
                    <wp:docPr id="3" name="Text Box 2"/>
                    <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                      <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>
                    </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                      <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                        <wps:wsp>
                          <wps:cNvSpPr txBox="1">
                            <a:spLocks noChangeArrowheads="1"/>
                          </wps:cNvSpPr>
                          <wps:spPr bwMode="auto">
                            <a:xfrm>
                              <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                              <a:ext cx="2360930" cy="1404620"/>
                            </a:xfrm>
                            <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                              <a:avLst/>
                            </a:prstGeom>
                            <a:noFill/>
                            <a:ln w="9525">
                              <a:noFill/>
                              <a:miter lim="800000"/>
                              <a:headEnd/>
                              <a:tailEnd/>
                            </a:ln>
                          </wps:spPr>
                          <wps:txbx>
                            <w:txbxContent>
                              <w:p w:rsidR="005E294E" w:rsidRPr="006C60DD" w:rsidRDefault="00B4473B" w:rsidP="00D157A3">
                                <w:pPr>
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                                  </w:rPr>
                                </w:pPr>
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AF5A48">
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:t>##PreferredName##</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                              </w:p>
                            </w:txbxContent>
                          </wps:txbx>
                          <wps:bodyPr rot="0" vert="horz" wrap="square" lIns="91440" tIns="45720" rIns="91440" bIns="45720" anchor="t" anchorCtr="0">
                            <a:spAutoFit/>
                          </wps:bodyPr>
                        </wps:wsp>
                      </a:graphicData>
                    </a:graphic>
                    <wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="margin">
                      <wp14:pctWidth>40000</wp14:pctWidth>
                    </wp14:sizeRelH>
                    <wp14:sizeRelV relativeFrom="margin">
                      <wp14:pctHeight>20000</wp14:pctHeight>
                    </wp14:sizeRelV>
                  </wp:anchor>
                </w:drawing>
              </mc:Choice>
              <mc:Fallback>
                <w:pict>
                  <v:shape w14:anchorId="729764EB" id="_x0000_s1027" type="#_x0000_t202" style="position:absolute;margin-left:234.75pt;margin-top:22.9pt;width:185.9pt;height:110.6pt;z-index:-251654144;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-width-percent:400;mso-height-percent:200;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:3.6pt;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:3.6pt;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-width-percent:400;mso-height-percent:200;mso-width-relative:margin;mso-height-relative:margin;v-text-anchor:top" o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#xA;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#xA;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#xA;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#xA;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#xA;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#xA;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#xA;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#xA;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#xA;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#xA;IQDdp8gFDwIAAPoDAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysU9tuGyEQfa/Uf0C817teXxqvjKM0qatK&#xA;6UVK+gGYZb2owFDA3k2/PgPrOFb7VpUHBMzMmTlnhvX1YDQ5Sh8UWEank5ISaQU0yu4Z/fG4fXdF&#xA;SYjcNlyDlYw+yUCvN2/frHtXywo60I30BEFsqHvHaBejq4siiE4aHibgpEVjC97wiFe/LxrPe0Q3&#xA;uqjKcln04BvnQcgQ8PVuNNJNxm9bKeK3tg0yEs0o1hbz7vO+S3uxWfN677nrlDiVwf+hCsOVxaRn&#xA;qDseOTl49ReUUcJDgDZOBJgC2lYJmTkgm2n5B5uHjjuZuaA4wZ1lCv8PVnw9fvdENYzOKLHcYIse&#xA;5RDJBxhIldTpXajR6cGhWxzwGbucmQZ3D+JnIBZuO2738sZ76DvJG6xumiKLi9ARJySQXf8FGkzD&#xA;DxEy0NB6k6RDMQiiY5eezp1JpQh8rGbLcjVDk0DbdF7Ol1XuXcHrl3DnQ/wkwZB0YNRj6zM8P96H&#xA;mMrh9YtLymZhq7TO7deW9IyuFtUiB1xYjIo4nVoZRq/KtMZ5SSw/2iYHR670eMYE2p5oJ6Yj5zjs&#xA;hqxv1iRJsoPmCXXwMA4jfh48dOB/U9LjIDIafh24l5Tozxa1XE3n8zS5+TJfvEfixF9adpcWbgVC&#xA;MRopGY+3MU97ohzcDWq+VVmN10pOJeOAZZFOnyFN8OU9e71+2c0zAAAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAA&#xA;ACEASRdX8t8AAAAKAQAADwAAAGRycy9kb3ducmV2LnhtbEyPy07DMBBF90j8gzVI7KjTkqQlxKkQ&#xA;D6lL2oLE0o0nD2GPo9htw993WMFuRnN059xyPTkrTjiG3pOC+SwBgVR701Or4GP/drcCEaImo60n&#xA;VPCDAdbV9VWpC+PPtMXTLraCQygUWkEX41BIGeoOnQ4zPyDxrfGj05HXsZVm1GcOd1YukiSXTvfE&#xA;Hzo94HOH9ffu6BR80pfdNKnpcJm9p9vh9aXJ4l6p25vp6RFExCn+wfCrz+pQsdPBH8kEYRWk+UPG&#xA;KA8ZV2Bglc7vQRwULPJlArIq5f8K1QUAAP//AwBQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAtoM4kv4AAADhAQAA&#xA;EwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/&#xA;1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC8BAABfcmVscy8ucmVsc1BLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQDdp8gF&#xA;DwIAAPoDAAAOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC4CAABkcnMvZTJvRG9jLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQBJ&#xA;F1fy3wAAAAoBAAAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGkEAABkcnMvZG93bnJldi54bWxQSwUGAAAAAAQABADz&#xA;AAAAdQUAAAAA&#xA;" filled="f" stroked="f">
                    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:t">
                      <w:txbxContent>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="005E294E" w:rsidRPr="006C60DD" w:rsidRDefault="00B4473B" w:rsidP="00D157A3">
                          <w:pPr>
                            <w:rPr>
                              <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                          </w:pPr>
                          <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AF5A48">
                            <w:rPr>
                              <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:t>##PreferredName##</w:t>
                          </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                      </w:txbxContent>
                    </v:textbox>
                    <w10:wrap type="tight"/>
                  </v:shape>
                </w:pict>
              </mc:Fallback>
            </mc:AlternateContent>
          </w:r>
          <w:r>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
          </w:r>
        </w:p>
      </w:ftr>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. We are investigating this issue.

Comment: @Juan Any update on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: its a bug that we will fix, but i dont have an ETA as of now

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @JuanBalmori I hope this will be resolved really quick!